# Python Matplotlib: postition of the x-axis label is not below stroke

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, x-axis

Postition of the x-axis label is not in the middle, see image. I would like the vertical axis label to be exactly under the stroke of a three bar block. I couldn´t find a parameter so solve the problem. Has somebody an idea?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Messwert1': [10, 5, 8],
    'Messwert2': [7, 3, 6],
    'Messwert3': [12, 10, 15],
    'Typ': ['Annn', 'Bnnn \n kkks', 'C']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Daten aus dem DataFrame extrahieren
x = df['Typ']
y1 = df['Messwert1']
y2 = df['Messwert2']
y3 = df['Messwert3']

# Balkenpositionen berechnen
bar_width = 0.2
x_pos = np.arange(len(x))

# Balkendiagramm erstellen
plt.bar(x_pos, y1, width=bar_width, label='Messwert1')
plt.bar(x_pos + bar_width, y2, width=bar_width, label='Messwert2')
plt.bar(x_pos + 2*bar_width, y3, width=bar_width, label='Messwert3')

# Achsentitel hinzufügen
plt.xlabel('Typ')
plt.ylabel('Messwerte')

# x-Achsenbeschriftung anpassen
plt.xticks(x_pos + bar_width, x, rotation='vertical', ha='right')

# Legende anzeigen
plt.legend()

# Diagramm anzeigen
plt.show()
```

[image: postition of the x-axis label is not below stroke]

Comment: Please provide a fully reproducible code to be able to generate your exact graph. Maybe you have dangling spaces?

Comment: Does my solution answer your question? If it does, you can click the gray check next to my solution to accept it. If not, please clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

They're offset because you have `ha="right"`. This means that the right side of the rotated text will be aligned with the tick marker. Change that to `ha="center"` and you will get your desired results. You may also want to add `plt.tight_figure()` before `plt.show()` since the rotated labels are pushing the `xlabel` outside of the figure area.

[image]